# Python3 permissions and installing ipython/jupyter extensions

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, sudo, jupyter

My question is two-fold, but I believe they are related:

1. I have recently realized that I have a permission issue with my python3 installation.  If I run `python3`, I cannot import any packages.  However, if I run `sudo python3`, all packages import flawlessly.  Similarly, I must run jupyter notebooks with sudo as well.  From reading, I believe I have made an error by installing many packages with `sudo pip`.  Is there a straightforward way to fix this?
2. I am trying to install ipython extensions without luck. Using 

   `sudo pip install https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/archive/master.zip --user`

   I receive an error `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`.

If I download the zip file, and run `sudo python3 setup.py install`, the error is: 

`IPython-notebook-extensions/configure_nbextensions.py", line 80, in <module>
    except (psutil.ZombieProcess, psutil.AccessDenied):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZombieProcess'`

If I run `python setup.py install`, the resulting error is:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.`

This is the **same** error that I get when importing a package from python (when opened with `python`, rather than `sudo python`) in the terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I don't know what you've done, but it sounds like your system is borked. If this is a VM or something where you don't have important data stored in it, I'd recommend blowing it away and starting again. If that's not practical: is `$PYTHONPATH` set? If you start `python`, what are `sys.version` and `sys.executable`?

Answer (score 0):

> except (psutil.ZombieProcess, psutil.AccessDenied):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZombieProcess'

From the message,The old version of psutil is missing these module.
you should update the package of psutil use:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade psutil
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:
`error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Can't roll back psutil; was not uninstalled`